# Regex matching for special characters between numbers

Tags: python, regex

Condition:
1 to 2 digit number followed by optional `[ . , ” ’]` + 1 to 4 digit number

Examples:

```
7 M
13.6 M
8.205m
9.,56m
```

Expected Results:

```
7
13.6
8.205
9.,56
```

Regex Pattern I've tried:

```
(?:^\d{1,2})(?:[\.\,\’\"]{0,2})\d{0,4}
```

This doesn't work as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can solve this also with a simple for loop in O(n) time. Seems to be more complex to understand a regex with the simple behavior. Or do you have to solve using regex?

Comment: Your regex already does exactly what you describe.

Comment: If I look at your regex then you're missing quite a few tests. There are more characters and more combinations valid (and invalid) then present in your input / output examples.

Comment: Your regex has  a trailing whitespace that hinders it to match your last 2 testcases - elsewise it can be simplified, try `r'^\d{1,2}[.,’\"]{0,2}\d{0,4}'`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the spaces in the character class and you don't have to escape the chars as well.

Matching optional digits `\d{0,4}` could possibly also match `13.`

You could make the second part optional inclusing the character class and the digits and use a quantifier `+`

```
^\d{1,2}(?:[.,”’]+\d{1,4})?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wb63I9/1)

If the M should be present, you could use a capturing group

```
^(\d{1,2}(?:[.,”’]+\d{1,4})?) ?[Mm]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oNIad0/1)